# uploadify: HTTP request sent to backend

Tags: http, post, uploadify, multipartform-data

I've a custom webserver which parses HTTP requests including multipart-form data.

In case of following, things are good:

```
<FORM method = "POST" action = "#" enctype multipart form-data multiple>
<INPUT type = "file"/>
<INPUT type = "submit"/>
</FORM>
```

The above HTML sends request which look like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2:8888
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/*
Content-Length: 884
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------1193f8fd031d

img 1

----------------------------1193f8fd031d

img 2

----------------------------1193f8fd031d--
```

In case I use uploadify as per its [docs](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/), I donot get similar HTTP request at the backend.

How can I view HTTP request which uploadify sends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server you can install Wireshark or try using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) on the client-side to view the HTTP communication.